# order comma separated values in a string in Postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-9.1, greenplum

Is there any way to reorder the values of string with ascending or descending order?

i.e.
values : u,a,c,a to a,a,c,u

Comment: Why do you store multiple values in a single field? That's a recipe for problems

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by doing an unnest on your string to break the values in multiple rows and then group by on it

Getting results in ASC order

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(str, ',')) as str
        FROM test_string
        order by 1,2 
     )
select ID, string_agg(str,',') final_string  
from cte 
group by id
order by final_string ;
```

[image]

Getting results in DESC order

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(str, ',')) as str
        FROM test_string
        order by 1,2 desc
     )
select ID, string_agg(str,',') final_string  
from cte 
group by id
order by final_string desc;
```

[image]

You can use the following code to reproduce the scenario.

```
    drop table if exists test_string;
create table test_string (id integer, str varchar(100));

insert into test_string (id, str) values (1, 'q,w,r');
insert into test_string (id, str) values (2, 'a,e,c');
insert into test_string (id, str) values (3, 'a,z,e');       
        
-- Getting results in ASC order
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(str, ',')) as str
        FROM test_string
        order by 1,2 
     )
select ID, string_agg(str,',') final_string  
from cte 
group by id
order by final_string ;

-- Getting results in DESC order
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(str, ',')) as str
        FROM test_string
        order by 1,2 desc
     )
select ID, string_agg(str,',') final_string  
from cte 
group by id
order by final_string desc;
```